# Верстка: правильное наложение слоев

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

Хочу сделать так, как на картинке, но не выходит :(

[image]

Я там вырезал прозрачную область, игрался с z-index но так и не вышло.
т.е. хочу чтобы картинка слайдера немного спускалась вниз и была под кнопкой навигации для слайдера, т.е. при активной кнопке чтобы появлялся под ней текущий слайд.

Вот живой пример, [верстка того что есть](http://vk.cc/1AHpLE).

Comment: Вам нужно белый фон убрать?

Comment: вы же сами на картинке там белую полосу сделали!!!
Сделайте продолжение фона и у вас все будет красиво.

Comment: Да мне нужно белый фон заменить картинкой со слайда, картинки на сладе то меняются, просто дорисовать не получится.
Фон не белый, он прозрачный на картинке.

Comment: На первом вашем примере все просто: есть 4 слайда (квадратные, насчет прозрачности не важно), а пространство под слайдами заполнено другим фоном (от изображения выше), не вырезайте вы область. Попробуйте все же разобраться с z-index

Comment: Я свежим взглядом посмотрел сейчас, оно наверно и не получится так. Слайд залезет и на остальную часть, а не только под областью навигации.